# Subscription plan vs credits

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, user-expectation, user-engagement, user-perception

I am working on a small commercial product and It is still early days, but I already try to think of ways to monetize this service. I would like to know what users prefer or in which situation the one's benefits would outweigh the other's and why.

For example, on stock resource sites, there is a clear steer towards credits, while on music subscription sites and services in general a monthly fee is charged. 
Now, of course this is a bit of an extreme example because music services where you would spend credits to listen to music would not really make sense, but I think you get idea as to where I am headed. 
My question specifically is, would you (maybe from personal experience) prefer going the credits route, and why ?

I think credits will bring in more money, yet the model does seem appealing to a user (I don't particularly hate credits, as a matter of fact, I really do not care too much whether a service should have been a monthly fee or not).
I think about the credits route because you can really give the user control about what he intends to use in a service as opposed to using all of it for a fixed (higher) fee, if that makes sense ...

Hope I can get some advice here.

Comment: Depends upon the pricing and what your competition is offering. What is the typical scenario?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about marketing strategy rather than User Experience. I feel that this question, even if it's an important one, really doesn't belong on UX.SE. The scope is to maximize revenue rather than implementing a good User Experience.

Comment: @BennySkogberg No I think you misunderstand. My goal is not revenue, but user experience. I have a model that could incorporate both a subscription model or the credits model, and I need to know which one is the preferred way for customers (solely from an experience standpoint) but not focussing on what would make more money...